# Will Soql written in Database.querylocator(query) will count against the total governor limits

Tags: asynchronous

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        List<Case> cstlist = new List<Case>([select id from case limit 10]);
        System.debug('this is the query limit in start@@'+limits.getQueries());
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id,owner.name,caseNumber,status 
         from Case limit 500]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Case> scope){
       //code
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
     List<Case> cstlist = new List<Case>([select id from case limit 10]);
     System.debug('this is the SOQL Query limits in Finish'+limits.getQueries());
     }   
}
//for the first debug , I saw the limit is 1
//for the finish method, I saw the limit is 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the limits start at zero for each transaction (start, each execute method, and finish). Running your exact code in my org results in the following output:

> this is the query limit in start@@1
>
> this is the SOQL Query limits in Finish1